# Is there a way for a VS2008 Web App Project to work on Windows 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis, windows-server-2008, vs-web-application-project

I have some web application projects in my solution that are set with the web tab in the project properties to use the local IIS server and create the web there.  This works fine for windows XP, windows 2003.

I want to open the project on Windows 2008 but the project gets the following popup when loading each of the projects with this type of web setting:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Is there something I need to do to enable this for Windows 2008?

Comment: this is a developer issue, not a sysadmin issue, it doesn't belong on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive, but off the top of my head...I'd make sure that you installed all of the IIS6 compatibility options for IIS7 (when you set up the Windows 2008 Server).

It sounds like you're missing some of the COM components that IIS6 would expose to deploy sites that way.

**EDIT**

As per the comments...here's the [instructions for insallation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397374.aspx).

Comment: You were right.  I found this before I came back to read the answers but you are correct.  I was able to determine this by editing the project and taking the projectextensions section out, then trying add the settings back in.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397374.aspx  gives steps on installing it (can't edit your answer or I would add this.)

Comment: He needs to install the Install IIS 6.0 Metabase Compatibility.  Windows Server 2008 has these to allow backwards compatbility with VS 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing that occurs to me is that on Windows Vista and 2008, Visual Studio needs to be run with elevated privileges (e.g. Run as Administrator). Are you doing that?

Comment: yea... the privledges are all taken care of